# How do I know what c# reference file I need for corresponding c++ header file

Tags: c#, interop, header-files

I am sure this is not a new question, but i don't know what or where to look at.
I want to convert this c++ program to c#.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389098(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
The sample includes dshow.h, but i found on an equivalent sample c# code that, what c# needs is quartz.dll.
how do I know dshow.h is included in quartz.dll? 
Another file includes window.h. what is the corresponding dll file?

Is that all COM library are available in system32 folder?

Are all .dll files convertible to RCW by tlbimp.exe? (I tried to convert kernel32.dll, but I can't. why's that?)

C++ use hr = object->function(); to get the return message. How do I do that in C#?

Comment: kernel32.dll is not a COM library. tlbimp converts .tlb files, (that can be contained in COM DLLs).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032800/directshow-in-c-sharp-for-windows-mobile-strategy

Comment: This isn't going work, DirectShow doesn't have a type library available.  This is the unfriendly kind of COM.  A .NET wrapper for dshow is available from [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thank you for all your attention.
i am actually asking a more general question.
when i see c++ code includes some header files, how do i know what dll files i should import for